# emacs lisp: How to remove/delete an element of a list?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I tried my first steps with emacs lisp to remove the element `"\\.synctex\\.gz"` from `LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes`:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(setq my-LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (remove '"\\.synctex\\.gz" LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes)); that's not working
  '(setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes
     (append my-LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (list "-blx\\.bib" "\\.run\\.xml"))))
```

How can I remove this element here? I found `remove` and `delete`, tried them both, but I get an `wrong-number-of-arguments`-type of error.

**Update**

I tried this:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  (setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (delete "\\.synctex\\.gz"  LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes))
  '(setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes
     (append LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (list "-blx\\.bib" "\\.run\\.xml"))))
```

but I receive quite a long output in *Backtrace* :-(

Comment: Looks like you just have a spacing error.  Remove the extra spacing of: `LaTeX-clean-  intermediate-suffixes` and you should be fine.

Comment: That was somehow a copy and paste error, I didn't have this in the code. I'll change the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you see is not due to manipulations of the list but caused by a wrong usage of eval-after-load. This function allows only two parameters: `(eval-after-load FILE FORM)`. So your snippet should read either

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (delete "\\.synctex\\.gz"  LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes)
         LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (append LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (list "-blx\\.bib" "\\.run\\.xml"))))
```

(as multiple assignments are allowed in a single setq statement) or the more general variant (subsuming as many forms as you wish within a single `progn`):

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(progn
     (setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (delete "\\.synctex\\.gz"  LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes))
     (setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (append LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (list "-blx\\.bib" "\\.run\\.xml")))))
```

Comment: you could also use `with-eval-after-load` which adds the progn and quoting for you:
```(with-eval-after-load 'latex ... ...)```

Answer (score 30):

As assem pointed out there seems to be extra whitespace in your code which prevents the otherwise correct invocation of `remove`.

Note that both `delete` and `remove` work for such purposes, as long as the elements of the list can be compared correctly via `equal` which is used for both of them. If you want to compare using `eq` instead, use the functions `delq` or `remq`.

The main differences between `delete` and `remove` (or `delq` and `remq` respectively) is that `delete` removes the given element by side effect, i.e., changes the given list in place, while `remove` does not but instead returns a copy of the given list with the element removed.

```
(setq list1 '("foo" "bar" "baz"))
(setq list2 (remove "bar" list1))

(message "list1: %s" list1)
(message "list2: %s" list2)

(setq list3 (delete "bar" list1))

(message "list1: %s" list1)
(message "list3: %s" list3)
```

If you evaluate the above code, you'll find the following output in your `*Message*` buffer:

```
list1: (foo bar baz)
list2: (foo baz)
list1: (foo baz)
list3: (foo baz)
```

As you can see, after calling `remove` on `list1`, it has not changed. But after you called `delete` on it, it has changed.

Answer (score 3):

`delete` should work
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html

```
(setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (delete "\\.synctex\\.gz"  LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes))
```

Comment: I still get the `debug(error (wrong-number-of-arguments...` error

Comment: Since, per the other answer, `delete` modifies lists in place, the `setq` is not necessary.